# How to hide placeholder events for invitations not replied to on a google calendar I'm subscribed to

Tags: google-calendar

I'm subscribed to my wife's google calendar. She got some spam calendar invitations, and she reported them as spam, however, the invitations are still showing up for me as placeholder events on her calendar. On my end, how can I still see events she has created or accepted, while hiding these invitations to which she hasn't accepted or declined?

I know there is a setting to [prevent unaccepted invitations from showing up on one's own calendar](https://techlifeweb.com/how-to-keep-unaccepted-events-google-calendar/), but I am not seeing a setting for this on my end - on the calendar I subscribed to (under "settings for other calendars" > [wife's calendar name]). There are only settings for notifications, ways to integrate the calendar, and a button to unsubscribe from the calendar.

I also would like to still show invitations to my personal calendar to show up as placeholders, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

> *...but I am not seeing a setting for this on my end - on the calendar I subscribed to (under "settings for other calendars" > [wife's
>   calendar name])*

You will **not** find it there.
**You have to look under**: `Settings` > `General` > `Event settings`
It is a **setting for all your calendars** not a specific one.

[image: calendar general settings]

Comment: Yes, I do know about this setting for all calendars. However, what I am looking for, as I mentioned in the question, is a way to disable showing previews for invitations on **only this subscribed calendar** while still showing previews for invitations on my personal calendar.

Comment: @MikeEng  _"Yes, I do know about this setting..."_ Well, in that case I'm afraid you ran out of luck. **No way for individual calendars**.

Comment: It’s a weird loophole that this spam event on my wife’s calendar still shows up for me. She marked it as spam, so it no longer shows up for her, even though she still has “show invitations” set to yes. Also, there is no way for me to mark the event as spam on my end.

Comment: Nothing you can do then. In any case , as per 
[site 
guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) since
the answer addressed your question (even though a negative one), you should 
[accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so 
others can benefit as well -. ([Why 
vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?) You can always come back and unvote if you solve this.

Comment: Well, I upvoted it, but I am not accepting it in order to encourage others to provide other answers as workarounds to address the underlying problem, even though there is no way to do it the way I was thinking of doing it.

Comment: Well done. I hope someone can come up with an acceptable answer.